# Rails how to automatic delete an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to automatic delete an object

My Konkurrancer model:

```
class Konkurrancer < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :kategori
end
```

I have an column named deadline with a date.
When the deadline is reached I want the object to be deleted.
How should I write the code and where should it go?

Comment: You want the object to be deleted from the db without any notice and without any chance to be brought back?

Comment: Yes. I want them to be deleted from the public view. But still I want to be able to see them in Admin panel as deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make column named `active` and set it to false when deadline is reached. Probably you need cron for checking the deadlines daily or hourly.

Comment: Also, to add to this, over a fixed period of time (say a week) you can perform a clean-up of objects that are marked as 'inactive'.

Comment: Should I make an action in the controller or should it go into the model?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems here:

- Soft delete (mark as deleted but keep the record). There are several plugins for rails that can help you: http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/activerecord_soft_delete.html
- Periodically checking a state and taking an action. Something as simple as cron job hitting a special (and hidden from others) URL can help or something more rails'y like BackgroundRB can help.

Comment: I am thinking of choose the solution mark as deleted. Should I then run a background task every day to see of the deadline is reached and if it is mark it as deleted.

Comment: You can run it as frequently as needed but make sure it is not putting extra weight on your system.